# VIM: Open netrw on startup or open files provided

Tags: vim

I've added a little quality-of-life improvement to the `.vimrc` which invokes netrw @ startup, namely:

```
augroup ProjectDrawer
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * :Explore!
augroup END
```

Works like a charm, however this interferes with invoking vim to edit a particular file `vim file_foo` (I end up with `netrw` not with `file_foo`).

How can I modify my `.vimrc` to e.g. invoke `ProjectDrawer` when there were no arguments to the vim on invocation (`vim`), otherwise open provided files (`vim file_foo`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a conditional that checks `argc()`, which gives the number of arguments passed to Vim (the arguments itself are returned by `argv({nr})`):

```
augroup ProjectDrawer
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | Explore! | endif
augroup END
```